# Periodicity of a Certain Generalized Power Series

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, power-series, periodic-functions

Good evening.  I am interested in the periodicity of the given power series.

$$H(k,x)=\sum_{j=0}^\infty\frac{x^{jk}}{(jk)!}$$

and by extension,

$$H(i,k,x)=\sum_{j=0}^\infty\frac{x^{jk+i}}{(jk+i)!}$$

A few notes:

1. If $k=1$,

> $H(1,x)=e^x$ and is periodic over $\mathbb{C}$ with period $2\pi i$.

2. If $k=2$, we have

> for $i=0$, $H(0,2,x)=\cosh{x}$ which is periodic over $2\pi i$
>
> for $i=1$, $H(1,2,x)=\sinh{x}$ which is periodic over $2\pi i$
>
> for $i=0$, $H(0,2,-x)=\cos{x}$ which is periodic over $2\pi$
>
> for $i=1$, $H(1,2,-x)=\sin{x}$ which is periodic over $2\pi$

Are the $H(n,m,x)$ periodic after this for larger values of $k$?  Or are the exponential and trig functions the exceptions?

EDIT:
The motivation behind this was to determine if the above functions could be written as infinite products just as the sine and cosine functions can be written as infinite products.  I was interested in $k=3$, as I was interested in the Apery's Constant problem.  I know this approach doesn't work as the Basel problem, but i thought I could still find interesting identities that way.  Below are the complex plots in mathematica.

[image]

Comment: If $\zeta$ is a primitive $k$th root of unity, note that $\sum_{t=0}^{j-1} \sum_{n=0}^\infty (\zeta^t x)^n/n! = k H(k,x)$. This lets you write $H(k,x)$ as a linear combination of values of the exponential function, which should help you understand its periodicity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is closely related to [series multisection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_multisection).

> **Theorem**  For analytic function $f(z)=\sum^\infty_{n=0}a_n z^n$, 
>   $$\sum^\infty_{m=0}a_{qm+p}\cdot z^{qm+p}=\frac1q\sum_{k=0}^{q-1}\omega^{-kp}f(\omega^k z)$$ where $\omega=e^{2\pi i/q}$, $p,q$ are integers and $0\le p\le q.$

Hence
$$H(j,k,x)=\frac1{k}\sum^{k-1}_{n=0}\omega^{-nj}\exp\left(\omega^n z\right)$$ where $\omega=e^{2\pi i/k}$.

Not to spoil everything, I will stop here and I am sure you can proceed with this hint.

---

Unfortunately, periodicity does not exist for $k\ge 3$.

Denote the period of the $n$th term in the summation $T_n$. Then,
$$T_n=\frac{2\pi i}{\omega^n}$$

If a ‘universal period’ exists, then for every $(n_1,n_2)$ pair, there exists positive coprime integers $a,b$ such that
$$aT_{n_1}=bT_{n_2}\implies \omega^{n_2-n_1}\in\mathbb Q$$

Take $n_2=n_1+1$. It is clear that there is no universal period for $k\ge 3$.

Comment: And that is what I was looking for.  Now, my ultimate goal here was to be able to write the multisection sum as an infinite product similar to sine and cosine.  It would therefore be helpful to know if I find a root, if it's periodic, what other roots would therefore look like.  Thank you.

Comment: @Eleven-Eleven Unfortunately things do not always go as you wish. Please see my edit.

Comment: I had a feeling.  I found roots using numerical methods when $k=3,$ and $i=1$, and when I plotted them, they appeared to be periodic in the complex plane along three vectors whose slopes are the third roots of unity.  But they perturb a bit the closer you get to the origin.  But they appear periodic to the eye....

Comment: @Eleven-Eleven This behaviour is surprising. Would you mind adding the plot the the OP?

Comment: I worked on this some time ago, I have to get to my math computer where I have mathematica.  But I will update with a plot in the coming day.

Comment: @Eleven-Eleven It seems like that the function is periodic for $k=4$. I will further investigate tomorrow.

Comment: With $k=4$, $H(4,x)=\cosh{x}+\cos{x}$.

Comment: I posted a plot of the function for $k=3,$ for each $i$.  It's not the roots speficially, but you can see the apparent periodicity of the roots along the root of unity vectors.